How to loop through Inner list of object
I have a need where I need to loop through sublist of each class.
public  Class A
{
public int IdA {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public  List<Class B> Items {get;set;}
}
public Class B
{
public string IdA {get;set;}
public string IdB {get;set;}
public string SecondName {get;set;}
public  List<Class C> Items {get;set;}
}

public Class C
{
public string IdB {get;set;}
public string IdC {get;set;}
public string ThirdName {get;set;}
public  List<Class D> Items {get;set;}
}

public Class D
{
public string IdC {get;set;}
public string IdD {get;set;}
public string FourthName {get;set;}

}



Class a = new class A {"a1","name1",{{"a1","b1","name2"}},{"a1","b2","name3",{"b2","c1","name3"}},{}}}
Class A is the main class , It will have a sub list of b and  Class B may have sub list of Class C and Class c may have sub list of D.
I wanted to loop through  each object of Class A and if it has the sub list of b then loop through it and  display each object in the table. If the there are sub list then there will be expand and collapse link.
I am looking for a general function to  loop through  any class with sub list and  display it when the use clicks the link button to see the sub list. I wanted to loop through the hierarchy
foreach(var A in List<A>)
{
Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
foreach(var B in A)
{
Console.WriteLine(b.SecondName)
foreach(var c in B)
{
 Console.WriteLine(c.ThirdName)
foreach(var D item in C)
{        
Console.WriteLine(b.FourthName )
}

} 

}
}

But how do I Know how many inner levels  nested?In the following picture Temporary file is the grandprents , c:\windows\temp* is the parents and the files under it is the children. the nested file relation.


foreach(var B in A) should be foreach(var B in A.Items) (etc). But you need to rethink your design. Classes B, C and D are really identical. If the number of levels isn't fixed, perhaps start by replacing these with a single class.

Its basically the tree structure , I have to write a code where the user can pass in any level of nested structure and show the hierarchy in the table   with expand and collapse link button. Can you suggest any solution for this . the table is basically to display the related files , like in windows folder  structure.

"any level of nested structure" for arbitrary classes? How would the code know what variable to loop over?

Check How to flatten a tree via LINQ. It's a lot easier to write such code when all tree nodes are either the same class eg Node or implement the same interface that returns the items

The list of files to loop over is always  names as List Items. Each nested level have to look for   count of items . If the count is 0 then there is no sub list further

Check How to flatten a tree. One of the answers is just a single line

You can use a base object and inheritance to simplify the code and make it more generic. This base object contains the common properties and a list of child items.
public class BaseObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BaseObject> Items { get; set; } = new List<BaseObject>();
}

Derive specific classes from the base class:
public class A : BaseObject
{
    public int IdA
    {
        get { return int.Parse(Id); }
        set { Id = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public new List<B> Items
    {
        get { return base.Items.ConvertAll(x => (B)x); }
        set { base.Items = value.ConvertAll(x => (BaseObject)x); }
    }
}

public class B : BaseObject
{
    public string IdA { get; set; }
    public string IdB
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    public new List<C> Items
    {
        get { return base.Items.ConvertAll(x => (C)x); }
        set { base.Items = value.ConvertAll(x => (BaseObject)x); }
    }
}

public class C : BaseObject
{
    public string IdB { get; set; }
    public string IdC
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    public new List<D> Items
    {
        get { return base.Items.ConvertAll(x => (D)x); }
        set { base.Items = value.ConvertAll(x => (BaseObject)x); }
    }
}

public class D : BaseObject
{
    public string IdC { get; set; }
    public string IdD
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }
}

Then use a recursive method to traverse through the hierarchy:
    static void Traverse(BaseObject obj, int level)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', level * 2) + $"{obj.GetType().Name}: {obj.Id}, {obj.Name}");
        foreach (var item in obj.Items)
        {
            Traverse(item, level + 1);
        }
    }
}

The recursive traversal function is simpler and can handle any level of nested lists.
